# How to customize Spinner in Android

Tags: android, helper

I have used spinner in my project but it looks like

[image]

But i want spinner as actual dropdownlist.Please help me.

like this

[image]

Comment: by actual dropdownlist u mean the 1 i pasted in the question??\

Comment: That looks like a dropdownlist to me. Could you elaborate?

Comment: this can be achieved by just using the default spinner, you dont need to customize for this

Comment: No!I want the view of dropdown list as below shown image.

Comment: yeah thats what....it can be achieved when u use, cityArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

Comment: if i dint understand your question...please paste the code where you are setting the adapter to the spinner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
city_array = new String[]{city1, city2, city3,....};

ArrayAdapter<String> cityArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,city_array);

cityArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

city_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(yourSpinner);
city_spinner.setAdapter(cityArrayAdapter);
```